# How do I write an rspec test for this before_validation callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, callback

I have a model that uses a before_validation callback to set the call_time attribute by integrating a call_time_time and call_time_date field from a form.

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :call_time_date, :call_time_time
  before_validation :set_call_time

  def set_call_time
    if call_time_date && call_time_time
      d = Date.parse call_time_date
      t = Time.parse call_time_time
      self.call_time = Time.local d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min
    end
  end
end
```

The set_call_time method is still quite underdeveloped (it fails with empty fields), but before I do any more I want it tested properly.

This is my current test. It passes, but I actually want it to fail and I don't understand why it's passing.

```
describe Attendance
  it "should be invalid if the call_time is not set in the parameters" do
    attendance = FactoryGirl.build :attendance, call_time: nil, call_time_time: nil, call_time_date: nil
    attendance.valid? #To trigger before_validation callback
    attendance.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

and here is the associated Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :attendance do
    call_time "2012-06-01 15:00"
  end
end
```

It seems like a lot of people have trouble testing before_validation callbacks, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're currently not validating anything at all... What I mean is: you should also add something like

```
validates_presence_of :call_time
```

to your model, in order to trigger the validation

Currently you're only executing your set_call_time method. Nothing more nothing less!